# Angular: Pass to a component a function, which once executed in the target component should call a local (to the target component) method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to pass from `<my-app>` component to `<app-my-sample>` component a batch of methods which should execute local methods in `<app-my-sample>`. I used `@ViewChild` to make this possible.

**Can I uncomment the code below (and adjust sth) to make the same without @ViewChild() ?**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h3> Angular 6</h3>
      Row1: <app-my-sample></app-my-sample><br>
      Row2: <app-my-sample [items]='arrayOfActions' #myhook></app-my-sample>
    `,
  styles: [ 'h3 { font-family: Lato; }' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  @ViewChild(MySampleComponent) myhook: MySampleComponent;

  arrayOfActions: ActionModel[] = [
        // THIS WORKS
        { myAction: () => this.myhook.myFunc1() }, 
        { myAction: () => this.myhook.myFunc2() }, 
        { myAction: () => this.myhook.myFunc1() }, 

        // ... BUT I WANT TO PASS THIS BATCH to <app-my-sample> i.e. without @ViewChild
        // and have the myFunc1 and myFunc2 methods inside <my-sample-component> called:
        // { myAction: () => this.myFunc1() },    
        // { myAction: () => this.myFunc2() },
        // { myAction: () => this.myFunc1() },

    ]
}
```

And `<app-my-sample>` :

```
export interface ActionModel {
    myAction: () => void;
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-sample',
    template: `
      <input 
          *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" 
          type="button"
          [value]="'BTN-'+i"
          (click)="item.myAction()"
          >
    `,
    styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class MySampleComponent  {
    @Input() items: ActionModel[] = [
        { myAction: () => this.myFunc1() },
        { myAction: () => this.myFunc2() },
        { myAction: () => this.myFunc1() },
    ];

    myFunc1() {
        console.log('Hi from myFunc1 !');
    }

    myFunc2() {
        console.log('Hi from myFunc2 !');
    }
}
```

Refer to this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-pass-a-method-to-call-a-method-on-target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a callback where you can execute methods on `MySampleComponent` without having to use `@ViewChild`.

Update your interface so that `MySampleComponent` is passed as a parameter.

```
export interface ActionModel {
    myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => void;
}
```

You can now use that parameter inside the callback to execute methods in `MySampleComponent`

```
 arrayOfActions: ActionModel[] = [
    { myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => comp.myFunc1() }, 
    { myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => comp.myFunc2() }, 
    { myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => comp.myFunc1() }
 ];
```

Update the `MySampleComponent` template so that it calls a method to execute the `myAction`

```
template: `
  <input 
      *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" 
      type="button"
      [value]="'BTN-'+i"
      (click)="callAction(item)"
      >
`
```

Now add the method to the `MySampleComponent` component

```
callAction(item: ActionModel) {
    item.myAction(this);
}
```

Comment: As proposed @cgTag revised in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zaggi-angular-pass-a-method-to-call-a-method-on-target-solved

Comment: great input ! Tnx for looking into it. A small update of your snippets - do you mean in the middle snippet 
{ myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => this.comp.myFunc1() }, OR { myAction: (comp: MySampleComponent) => comp.myFunc1() }, ? (the this. shouldn't be necessary here)

Comment: Yes the `this.comp` was a mistake. I've updated my answer. Can you accept if this works for you.